# asp.net mvc 4 how to bind click event to a viewmodel method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I would like to bind the click event of a checkbox to a method of my viewmodel. If the checkbox is selected, then other checkboxes of the view should appear.

What is the best approach for doing so ?

Comment: Are you using mvvm pattern?

Comment: I'm thinking of having a method in the ViewModel such as ToggleCheckbox(){ some logic based on viewmodel properties }. But I'm not too sure how to call that method from the View when the user click on the checkbox.

Comment: no I'm not using mvvm partern (do you mean using knockout.js ?).

Comment: Don't put methods in your viewModel.